# Disable Selinux from docker container service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, selinux

In my docker container , i notice that wehn running ll on the majority of my file , i ve got a "**.**" in the end of the access codes

**Example :**

```
[user@3a18ecb8ccd4 opt]$ ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4096 Sep  5 14:52 application
```

Since its affects my volume mounting , i want to disable this from my container : `drwxr-xr-x.`   **->**    `drwxr-xr-x`

Since i'm using ***docker-compose*** , i ve tried the option :z within my volumes mapping , but that didn't ameliorate it .

how my i do it ?

**Dokcer compose file :**

```
myapp:

    image: myImage3
    networks:
      - default
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
    - /opt/application/i99/current/logs:/opt/application/i99/current/logs:z
    tty: true
    ports:
      - target: 8300
        published: 8300
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: Did anybody ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @McFizz that seems no